# Linked List Function Calls

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, linked-list

I am almost finished with a LinkedList Program but cannot figure out this one compliler error regarding my insert and remove function. Other parts of the tester file seem to call it just fine except the last test bit.

I'll post the whole thing just to be safe:

Header:

```
#ifndef LINKEDLIST_H
#define LINKEDLIST_H

#include <iostream>

template <class T>
class Node
{
 public:
 T m_data;                  // Data to be stored
 Node<T>* m_next;     // Pointer to the next element in the list


 // Purpose: Default constructor
 // Postconditions: next pointer set to NULL
 // ---INLINE---
 Node() : m_next(NULL) {}

 // Purpose: Auxiliaty constructor, construct from parameters
 // Postconditions: data and next pointer set to parameters
 // ---INLINE---
 Node(const T& x, Node<T>* p)
         : m_data(x), m_next(p) {}

};

template <class T>
class LinkedList
{

 public:
 Node<T>* head;     // Pointer to the head of the list

// Purpose: Default constructor
// Postconditions: head pointer set to NULL
// ---INLINE---
 LinkedList() : head(NULL) {}


// Purpose: puts the data value x at the position pointed by pos
// Parameters: x is data value to inserted
//     pos pointer to the position to insert x at.
// Preconditions: pos is a pointer to a node in this list.
// Postconditions: x is inserted at the position pointed by pos
void insert(const T& x, Node<T>* pos);

// Purpose: removed the element in the position pointed by pos
// Parameters: pos pointer to the position to remove.
// Preconditions: pos is a pointer to a node in this list.
// Postconditions: position pointed by pos is removed from the list
void remove(Node<T>* pos);
```

IMPLEMENTATION of insert and remove

```
template <class T>
void LinkedList<T>::remove(Node<T>* pos)
{
 Node<T>* tmp;
 tmp = pos->m_next;
 pos->m_data = tmp->m_data;
 pos->m_next = tmp->m_next;
 delete tmp;
}

template <class T>
void LinkedList<T>::insert(const T& x, Node<T>* pos)
{
 Node<T>* tmp;
 tmp = new Node<T>;
 tmp->m_data = pos->m_data;
 tmp->m_next = pos->m_next;
 pos->m_data = x;
 pos->m_next = tmp;
}
```

MAIN PROGRAM

```
void test05() {

LinkedList<int> A;
Node<int>* tmp;

cout << endl << endl;
cout << " ***************** " << endl;
cout << " *  TEST SET #5  * " << endl;
cout << " ***************** " << endl;


//TEST : Panics on an empty list
cout << endl << "TEST : Panics on an empty list" << endl;
cout << A << endl;
cout << "Size of A = " << A.size() << endl;
tmp = A.getFirstPtr();
cout << "First = " << tmp << endl;
tmp = A.getLastPtr();
cout << "Last = " << tmp << endl;

//TEST : Inserting 10 elements to a
cout << endl << "TEST : Inserting 10 elements into A" << endl;
for (int k=0; k<10; k++){
  A.insert_front(k*11);
}
cout << A << endl;
cout << "Size of A = " << A.size() << endl;


//TEST : Panics on Invalid Index
cout << endl << "TEST : Panic on Invalid Index" << endl;
tmp = A.getAtPtr(99);
cout << tmp << endl;
A.insert(42,99);
A.remove(100);


 //TEST : Clearing A
 cout << endl << "TEST : Clearing A" << endl;
 A.clear();
 cout << A << endl;
 cout << "Size of A = " << A.size() << endl << endl;

 cout << "Test 05 - Done!" << endl;
}

int main () {

cout << "Hello World!!, This is the LinkedList LARGE Tester" << endl;

test01();
test02();
test03();
test04();
test05();


cout << "LARGE Done!" << endl;
return 0;
}
```

I edited out the other test calls because they are working correctly. The program works fine when I comment out the remove and insert in TEST 5 so I've narrowed it down to that. The compiler is saying that there is no matching function for call to the remove and insert and but that it is a near match.

Comment: What if you want to remove the last node in a list? If you walk through I expect you have an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Your `insert` and `remove` methods take a `Node<T> *` parameter, but these lines:

```
A.insert(42,99);
A.remove(100);
```

are passing integers. You probably want to pass `tmp` instead of `99`, but you will have to do another search to find the equivalent for `100`.